# How to display from html a local image using relative path with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In an electron app (mine is developped with quasar), how to display an image **relative** to the current path using `<img>` ?

I tried some stuff like that :

```
<img src='./dir/img.jpg'/>
<img src='file:./dir/img.jpg'/>
<img src='file://./dir/img.jpg'/>
<img src='file:///./dir/img.jpg'/>
```

...But none of them work.

NOTE : the image are not in asset and should be relative to the current directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron JS Images from Local File System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272451/electron-js-images-from-local-file-system)

Comment: this question answers it for *absolute* paths, Not relative ones

Comment: is this development or build?

Comment: Logging `__dirname` will probably be informative.

Comment: @The Foot : development mainly since in build, you can open the index html (even though it is not advised from quasar doc