# image cannot load html

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I have my images in the public/css folder, but when I copy the full path into the src,

[image]

the console always returns the `404` error that the image is not found. The path I am using is like this:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/Web Development/myBlog/views/greenteaswisscakeroll.JPG.
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I would not want my name in the path either, how can I add the image properly?

Comment: I think, You can find the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272451/electron-js-images-from-local-file-system

Answer (score 0):

The current image path is coming from root /, but after checking your project root /, it seems you need to enter the path from the project root /. For example, if the myblog directory becomes the root directory, you must enter the path as follows.

```
<img src='views/[filename].jpg' />
```